# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease

Tags: syntax-error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type androidx.activity.R$id is defined multiple times: C:\GymsGenius\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\5aeafbeccb117d4b736d800267b3a65fe175116feb5e422f7748aebf1c817c9c_0.jar:classes.dex, C:\GymsGenius\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\cda950a839a088c8deead71a59d51fe5d00937b888ac9db07476f342eb8470a9_0.jar:classes.dex

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\GymsGenius\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\5aeafbeccb117d4b736d800267b3a65fe175116feb5e422f7748aebf1c817c9c_0.jar:classes.dex